# HTML/CSS Scale div over full site when scrollbars appear

Tags: css, html, scale

I have the problem that a div is not scaling over the full page when the page is not fully seen, i.e. scroll bars appear at the bottom.

*Scales fine:*

[image]

*Does not scale fine when seen part is too small:*

[image]

**How can this be fixed?** Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gdztn/29/

*Clarification*: The inner div *must always* be 800 px wide while *the outter div* should scale over **the whole** width of the page. As you can see in the second image, the outter div does not reach the right end of the page when scrollbars appear.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about what precisely you're trying to accomplish. Do you just want `#head div:first-child` to always fill the full width of the viewport? If so, set `width:100%` for `#head div:first-child` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/gdztn/35/

Comment: scrollbar appears coz you have div:first-child width set to a fixed 800px. Change it to % so you wouldn't see a scrollbar.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want `#head` to always be 800px wide and for its child `div` element to fill the full width, change the `width` property of `#head` to 800px and that of the child div to 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/gdztn/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the `#head` width is 100% and the inner div has a fixed width. if you scale the page down, it's still 100% but smaller than the inner div. it's like having a smaller container and an exceedingly bigger content which overflows.

to address this problem, you should set `min-width` of the `#head` to keep it from shrinking smaller than the inner div, like `min-width: 850px`

http://jsfiddle.net/gdztn/43/

EDIT: also remove `position:absolute` from `#head`. if actually needed to be absolute, then add `width:100%`

Comment: This is most of the way there. Just setting the `min-width` however will cause `#head` not to span the full width unless it's <=850px. To fix this, add `width:100%;` to `#head` after you define the `min-width`. http://jsfiddle.net/gdztn/42/

Comment: the `#head` will  always have 100% because `min-width` just sets minimum width and not the width itself. plus, `div` elements are block-level  elements. unless they float, given a width, or are taken out of the flow (position absolute/fixed), they are always 100%

Comment: this does not appear to be true of absolutely positioned divs, as in this example, including in the jsfiddle you provided. Stretch the frames to the left to widen the "Result" panel and you will see `#head` does not grow past 850px unless told to do so.

Comment: Good solution, Joseph! Removing the absolute position and setting a min-width. That should do the trick for sure. +1

Comment: That is indeed a great solution and seems to fit my needs perfectly. Thank you very much, Joseph!